# can not write to file with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I use the below code in my project

```
file=sample.txt
awk 'BEGIN{print"5" > "/home/myName/${file}"}'
```

The code doesn't work and doesn't write to the existing sample.txt file, it actually creates a ${c}.txt file in the myName directory and writes 5 in it.
But when I simply write the file name instead of using the variable it works fine.the below code works:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print"5" > "/home/myName/sample.txt"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becouse of single quotes,

```
a="tmp.txt"
awk 'BEGIN{print"5" > "'$a'"}'
```